# When starting tmux it says Restored session despite removed resurrect

Tags: bash, tmux

After removing tmux resurrect and cleaning the whole folder ~/.tmux/ while starting tmux in bash (MacOsX El Captain) I am getting infromation:

"Restored session: Thu Sep 15 17:15:04 CEST 2016"

I am assuming that I have not removed entirely tmux ressurrect or tmuxinator but I can't figure out a way to disable it.

EDIT:

1. find / tmux - no files or directories found
2. find / resurrect - no files or directories found
3. after uninstalling and reinstalling again tmux (using brew) still didn't help

EDIT2: output of command 
    cat tmux-server-4144.log | grep session

```
1473953899.570430 cmdq 0x7fe92ae04d10: bind-key $ command-prompt -I#S "rename-session '%%'"
1473953899.570436 preparing state for bind-key $ command-prompt -I#S "rename-session '%%'" (client 0x0)
1473953899.573639 cmdq 0x7fe92ae09cd0: new-session
1473953899.573643 preparing state for new-session (client 0x7fe92c003000)
1473953899.573646 cmd_find_current_session: have client 0x7fe92c003000
1473953899.573661 cmd_find_current_session: have client 0x7fe92c003000
1473953899.574922 new session 0 $0
1473953899.574926 session 0 activity 1473953899.574925 (last 0.000000)
1473953899.575243 session 0 created
1473953899.575270 session 0 activity 1473953899.575268 (last 1473953899.574925)
1473953899.575291 session 0 has 3 references
1473953899.575295 session 0 has 2 references
1473953899.587201 input_parse: %0 ground, 49 bytes: Restored session: Thu Sep 15 17:35:52 CEST 2016\r\n
1473953902.034714 session 0 activity 1473953902.034710 (last 1473953899.575268)
1473953902.034724 session 0 not pasting
1473953902.201937 session 0 activity 1473953902.201934 (last 1473953902.034710)
1473953902.201943 session 0 not pasting
1473953902.306065 session 0 activity 1473953902.306061 (last 1473953902.201934)
1473953902.306073 session 0 not pasting
1473953902.402305 session 0 activity 1473953902.402301 (last 1473953902.306061)
1473953902.402313 session 0 not pasting
1473953902.834269 session 0 activity 1473953902.834265 (last 1473953902.402301)
1473953902.834277 session 0 not pasting
1473953902.834674 input_parse: %0 ground, 17 bytes: Saving session...
1473953902.856287 session 0 has 2 references
1473953902.856292 session 0 destroyed
1473953902.856295 session 0 has 2 references
1473953902.856298 session 0 has 1 references
1473953902.856334 session 0 freed (0 references)
```

---

Answer (score 5):

El Capitan's terminal session *should* only run under new Apple Terminal windows, but affects all interactive bash sessions regardless of terminal. Oops.

Run `touch ~/.bash_sessions_disable` to disable it.